# Tomcat HtmlUnit filter does not see requested URLs

Tags: java, ajax, google-app-engine, tomcat, htmlunit

I have a web.xml similar to this:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>crawlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>path.CrawlFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>crawlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>controlPanelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>path.ControlPanelServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>controlPanelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/path/controlPanel</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is, that my filter does not catch any of the requested URLs (that I need to filter out the `_escaped_fragment_` for Google Bot) . When I print out `servletRequest.getQueryString()` it always returns `null`.

In fact the only URIs that get printed by `getRequestURI()` are `/path/controlPanel` (like the url-pattern for the servlet).

How can I set my filter to see the full URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an App Engine problem. I had to use **jsp instead of html** and JDK instead of JDE.